# Bar Button not showing on toolbar xcode 5

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem

I wonder if anyone has faced this problem. 
I am adding a toolbar at the bottom of the view controller. I can see the toolbar but not any buttons on it. This is only happening with only of the view Controllers. The buttons seems to be hidden. If i double click on the button it does shows the editable text region with the text.

I know in the worst case, i can redesign the whole controller from scratch but i was wondering if anyone has faced this problem too or if i have just messed up some settings for this viewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the reason why it was not working. By default showToolbar button in the navigation controller is not checked. To fix it either you can tick the showToolbar or

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

in your viewDidLoad method to show the bottom toolbar in a particular view Controller. :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope you've already found an answer, but I just had an issue of "hidden" bar buttons as an issue of color. My navigation controller was in blue and after some custom changes and switching back to the "system" buttons I wasn't able to see them.